# Table pagination using bootstrap is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, pagination

I have used the below code for table pagination including the javascript provided by bootstrap. I have three links in the pagination, `"1", "2", "3"` which will open the respective number of rows under the table, when I click on the next button after i opened page `"3", "1"` should be replaced by `"4", "2"` by `"5"`, and `"3"` by `"6"`,

[image: I have clicked "3" and on clicking next, it should be in order "4", "5", "6"]

These are my JS and html file

html

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-hover">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>#</th>
              <th>Table heading</th>
              <th>Table heading</th>
              <th>Table heading</th>
              <th>Table heading</th>
              <th>Table heading</th>
              <th>Table heading</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody id="myTable">
            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>Table cell</td>
              <td>Table cell</td>
              <td>Table cell</td>
              <td>Table cell</td>
              <td>Table cell</td>
              <td>Table cell</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>2</td>
              <td>Table cell</td>
              <td>Table cell</td>
              <td>Table cell</td>
              <td>Table cell</td>
              <td>Table cell</td>
              <td>Table cell</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>3</td>
              <td>Table cell</td>
              <td>Table cell</td>
              <td>Table cell</td>
              <td>Table cell</td>
              <td>Table cell</td>
              <td>Table cell</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>4</td>
              <td>Table cell</td>
              <td>Table cell</td>
              <td>Table cell</td>
              <td>Table cell</td>
              <td>Table cell</td>
              <td>Table cell</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="success">
              <td>5</td>
              <td>Table cell</td>
              <td>Table cell</td>
              <td>Table cell</td>
              <td>Table cell</td>
              <td>Table cell</td>
              <td>Table cell</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>6</td>
              <td>Table cell</td>
              <td>Table cell</td>
              <td>Table cell</td>
              <td>Table cell</td>
              <td>Table cell</td>
              <td>Table cell</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>7</td>
              <td>Table cell</td>
              <td>Table cell</td>
              <td>Table cell</td>
              <td>Table cell</td>
              <td>Table cell</td>
              <td>Table cell</td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
              <td>8</td>
              <td>Table cell</td>
              <td>Table cell</td>
              <td>Table cell</td>
              <td>Table cell</td>
              <td>Table cell</td>
              <td>Table cell</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>9</td>
              <td>Table cell</td>
              <td>Table cell</td>
              <td>Table cell</td>
              <td>Table cell</td>
              <td>Table cell</td>
              <td>Table cell</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>10</td>
              <td>Table cell</td>
              <td>Table cell</td>
              <td>Table cell</td>
              <td>Table cell</td>
              <td>Table cell</td>
              <td>Table cell</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>11</td>
              <td>Table cell</td>
              <td>Table cell</td>
              <td>Table cell</td>
              <td>Table cell</td>
              <td>Table cell</td>
              <td>Table cell</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>12</td>
              <td>Table cell</td>
              <td>Table cell</td>
              <td>Table cell</td>
              <td>Table cell</td>
              <td>Table cell</td>
              <td>Table cell</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>   
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
      <ul class="pagination pagination-lg pager" id="myPager"></ul>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

js file:

```
$.fn.pageMe = function(opts){
    var $this = this,
        defaults = {
            perPage: 7,
            showPrevNext: false,
            hidePageNumbers: false
        },
        settings = $.extend(defaults, opts);

    var listElement = $this;
    var perPage = settings.perPage; 
    var children = listElement.children();
    var pager = $('.pager');

    if (typeof settings.childSelector!="undefined") {
        children = listElement.find(settings.childSelector);
    }

    if (typeof settings.pagerSelector!="undefined") {
        pager = $(settings.pagerSelector);
    }

    var numItems = children.size();
    var numPages = Math.ceil(numItems/perPage);

    pager.data("curr",0);
    var curr = 0;

    if (settings.showPrevNext){
        $('<li><a href="#" class="prev_link">«</a></li>').appendTo(pager);
    }

    $('<li><a href="#" class="page_link">'+(1)+'</a></li>').appendTo(pager);
    $('<li><a href="#" class="page_link">'+(2)+'</a></li>').appendTo(pager);
    $('<li><a href="#" class="page_link">'+(3)+'</a></li>').appendTo(pager);

   /* var curr = 0;
    while(numPages > curr && (settings.hidePageNumbers==false)){
        $('<li><a href="#" class="page_link">'+(curr+1)+'</a></li>').appendTo(pager);
        curr++;
    }*/

    if (settings.showPrevNext){
        $('<li><a href="#" class="next_link">»</a></li>').appendTo(pager);
    }

    //pager.find('.page_link:first').addClass('active');
    pager.find('.prev_link').hide();
    if (numPages<=1) {
        pager.find('.next_link').hide();
    }
      pager.children().eq(1).addClass("active");

    children.hide();
    children.slice(0, perPage).show();

    pager.find('li .page_link').click(function(){
        var clickedPage = $(this).html().valueOf()-1;
        goTo(clickedPage);
        return false;
    });
    pager.find('li .prev_link').click(function(){
        previous();
        return false;
    });
    pager.find('li .next_link').click(function(){
        next();
        return false;
    });

    function previous(){
        var goToPage = parseInt(pager.data("curr")) - 1;

        goTo(goToPage);
    }

    function next(){
        goToPage = parseInt(pager.data("curr")) + 1;

        goTo(goToPage);
    }

    function goTo(page){
        var startAt = page * perPage,
            endOn = startAt + perPage;

        children.css('display','none').slice(startAt, endOn).show();

        if (page>=1) {
            pager.find('.prev_link').show();
        }
        else {
            pager.find('.prev_link').hide();
        }

        if (page<(numPages-1)) {
            pager.find('.next_link').show();
        }
        else {
            pager.find('.next_link').hide();
        }

        pager.data("curr",page); 
        if(page >=1) {
            document.getElementByClassName(".page_link").value = curr + 1;
            pager.data("curr",page);
        }
        pager.children().removeClass("active");
        pager.children().eq(page+1).addClass("active");

    }
};

$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#myTable').pageMe({pagerSelector:'#myPager',showPrevNext:true,hidePageNumbers:false,perPage:2});

});
```

Please help

Comment: I think this link is helpful: http://botmonster.com/jquery-bootpag/#.WBxNNS197cs

Comment: or u can use http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Simple-Customizable-Pagination-Plugin-with-jQuery-Bootstrap-Twbs-Pagination/

Answer (score 0):

When you do `$('#myTable').pageMe(...)`, `listElement.children();` finds the `<thead>` and `<tbody>` elements.

Use `$('#myTable tbody')` to find the `<tr>` elements.