# bootstrap table pagination going out of screen

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, pagination

My table has n number of rows and if I use pagination for table ,the pager is very big. Is there any way to limit the pagination . for example, the pagination should contain 1,2,3 and on clicking next, the 1,2,3 should be replaced by 4,5,6 and so on . so that the pagination will not go out of screen. I tried many changes with my code and it is not working . Can anyone please help me out of this?

Comment: If you just want to adjust the size: Add class .pagination-lg for larger blocks or .pagination-sm for smaller blocks

Comment: Thank you. But even if i adjust the size, the pagination is very lengthy as the table may contain more than 500 rows .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Table pagination using bootstrap is not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40416972/table-pagination-using-bootstrap-is-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

I found a jQuery plugin that should be very helpful. Here is a [link](http://botmonster.com/jquery-bootpag/#example-simple).

Once you have the things set up with this code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//raw.github.com/botmonster/jquery-bootpag/master/lib/jquery.bootpag.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content">Dynamic Content goes here</div>
    <div id="page-selection">Pagination goes here</div>
    <script>
        // init bootpag
        $('#page-selection').bootpag({
            total: 10
        }).on("page", function(event, /* page number here */ num){
             $("#content").html("Insert content"); // some ajax content loading...
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

You can then use this:

```
 $('.demo3').bootpag({
   total: 500,
   page: 3,
   maxVisible: 3,
   href: "#pro-page-{{number}}",
   leaps: false,
   next: 'next',
   prev: null
}).on('page', function(event, num){
    $(".content3").html("Page " + num); // or some ajax content loading...
});
```

Let me know if this helped.